# Nodejs require returns undefined on production server

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am using a separated module to manage mongodb operations in my nodejs app.
Locally it works well but when i load my app on the production server it says `collectionDriver` is undefined.
This is where i require the module:

```
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
Server = require('mongodb').Server;
CollectionDriver = require('./collectionDriver').CollectionDriver;
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server(mongoHost, mongoPort));
mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) {
  if (!mongoClient) {
      console.error("Error! Exiting... Must start MongoDB first");
      process.exit(1);
  }
  var db = mongoClient.db("MyDatabase");
  collectionDriver = new CollectionDriver(db);
});
```

Comment: Just to be safe: You are using the exact same environment (node version, npm modules)? If yes, could it be that on the production server is a folder or json file named as your 'collectionDriver'?
See https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules

Comment: make sure you dont have a typo regarding upper cases. I found requiring a file on MacOs through `require('./lowerCase')` with a file `LowerCase.js` works but fails on linux

Comment: File name is the same and there are no other files with the same name.